# Is it possible to execute a VIM script in a non-interactive mode?

Tags: vim, scripting

The Gnats bug tracker has a command (edit-pr) that opens a ticket in $EDITOR.  My $EDITOR is VIM, and when this command opens the ticket in $EDITOR, I'd like to automatically perform some scripted edits without having to make any additional keystrokes.

Is there a way to write a VIM script that can be run non-interactively like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used gnats, so it's hard to say what exactly `edit-pr` is expecting to be done. But from what you've given us, you could try changing the EDITOR env variable to a custom shell script, or maybe even a python script or something.

```
EDITOR=/path/to/script.(sh|py) edit-pr <args>
```

But like I said, I don't know what kind of edits it wants, or what needs to be done in the editor. Maybe if you gave us an example of what you'd want to automate?

Comment: The gnats command was just an example.  I was looking for a general solution and I think your answer is the way to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Even though you've already received an answer to your question, others might find this useful.

Vim commands can also be specified in a file which is executed using the `-s` option:

```
    vim -s commands.txt file
```

Example:

```
    echo 'gg=G' > indent.txt
    echo ':wq' >> indent.txt
    vim -s indent.txt file
```

This will use Vim to indent the contents of file, save and exit.

Answer (score 14):

Vim commands can be specified on the command line when you run the program like this:

```
vim file.txt "+:s/foo/bar/g"
```

You can keep adding commands by adding `"+[cmd]"` arguments. You can either end there and the editor will open, run those commands and wait or you, or you can add a `"+:wq"` to save and close the file.

You could also write a script using vimscript syntax and either wrap it in a function to call when the file opens or in a separate script to import and apply to the buffer using the syntax above.

Answer (score 7):

To execute vim in non-interactive mode, you can use either `+{command}`/`-c {command}` or `-s` parameter which will allow you to execute the vim commands after the first file has been read.

Check few examples below.

Simple standard input and output using pipes can be achieved by the command:

```
$ echo Example | vim -es '+:wq! /dev/stdout' /dev/stdin | cat
```

To edit one file and save the changes to another:

```
$ vim -es '+:0,$s/127/128/g' '+:wq! new_file' /etc/hosts
$ cat file1 file2 | vim - -es '+:0,$s/foo/test/g' '+:wq! file3'
```

To edit file in-place, you can use `-s {scriptin}` so the  script  file is read, in example:

```
$ echo ':0,$s/foo/test/ge' > cmds.txt
$ echo ':wq' >> cmds.txt
$ vim -s cmds.txt -es file
```

To parse file and send it to pipeline's output, you may try the following:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts | vim -es '+:0,$s/127/128/g' '+%print' '+:q!' /dev/stdin | cat
```

or:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts | vim -es '+:0,$s/127/128/g' '+:wq! /dev/stdout' /dev/stdin | cat
```

See more: [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467) at Vim SE

Comment: Very handy! Any idea what resource backs Vim's pager, e.g. where `:hi` is scrollable and shows `-- More -- SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit`? It doesn't appear in the buffer list, and writing with `:w` writes an empty file (and the 'enter' keystroke causes the pager to scroll or exit.) I can use `:redir! >file | :hi | :redir END `, which captures as much as I scroll. I think it may work mechanically like a 2-directional `more`. I have to wonder why `:help` and `:hi` aren't both paged or both RO-buffered...